# Arduino multiplexing help needed.

Tags: arduino, led, multiplexer

Is it possible to use an 8 output demux to switch between seven 16 output demux's in the case that I want to control several LED's with an arduino uno? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. If you want to build a 7 to 128 demux with 3-to-8 and 4-to-16 demuxes, then put the 3 high bits of your output address into the 3-to-8, and use the outputs of that as the input enable to the individual 4-to-16 demuxes (assuming that it has an enable pin), so the output #0 on the 3-to-8 would go to the input enable of the first 4-to-16 demux, the output #1 would go to the second, etc.

Then you send the lower 4 bits of the address to all of the 4-to-16 demuxes. Ultimately you should get one wire high as a result out of 128.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a need for any other components? Transistors? Other than resistors?

Comment: No other components I can think of, except possibly inverters if the input enable is the wrong polarity. Also check that your demux can source enough current to power the LED, if not then you may need to use a transistor to boost the current. @SamuelPogue

Comment: I am attempting to simulate this using CDS using a 74LS138 as the 3-to-8, and 7 74HC154's for the 4-to-16's. I have it set to where SPDT's represent the address outputs on the arduino where one lead is connected to Vcc, and the other is connected to digital ground. However something is going wrong here and the LED's won't light. Because I have all the anodes of the LED's soldered together, and the cathodes have to be the ones to connect to the outputs of the 4-to-16's, I am assuming I am doing something wrong with the Enables. Of course, I am trying to discern why there are multiple Enables.

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with **one** 16 output demux: You could use a 3-of-8 active HIGH decoder for the positive input of the LED, and one 4-of-16 active LOW decoder for the negative input, and wire up the LEDs in a matrix of 8 rows and 16 columns.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgYcKz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Oooh could you elaborate?

Comment: I tried adding a diagram to illustrate the idea. Note that the 74HC238, used as an example, allows a maximum output current of 20mA. The 74HC238 is active HIGH, while the 74HC154 is active LOW.

Comment: Alright. This would work and most likely be more efficient, if I had not soldered all 109 anodes of the LED's together already (I was originally going to simply run all lights in a parallel, Having them on all the time and just recently decided that making them run in sequences would be more amusing). Now having done that, would it just make more sense to use Tim's proposed design, simply run a constant HIGH to the LED's, and invert a pin coming from the arduino to the first demux's input?

Comment: Yes, I agree, under those circumstances, @Tim’s design makes more sense.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the reverse voltage for the LED is 5V therefore, running from a 5V supply is close to exceeding the absolute rating of the LED. 3V3 supply is no problem but the current limit resistor would be more like 68 ohms to achieve near full brightness.